# Show that $B(x)=B(x^2)(1+x+x^2)$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $b_n$ - number of way to write $n$ as a sum of power of $2$. Every power can occur at most $2$ times (for example $6=2^2+2^1=2^2+2^0+2^0=2^1+2^1+2^0+2^0$ so $b_6=3$) and $b_0=1$. 
> Show that $B(x)=B(x^2)(1+x+x^2)$ where $B(x)$ is string creation function $b_n$.

$$B(t)=(1+t^{2^0}+t^{2\cdot 2^0})(1+t^{2^1}+t^{2\cdot 2^1}) ... = (1+t+t^2)(1+t^2+t^4)(1+t^4+t^8) ... = \frac{1-t^3}{1-t} \cdot \frac{1-t^6}{1-t^2} \cdot \frac{1-t^{12}}{1-t^4} \cdot \frac{1-t^{24}}{1-t^8}\cdot ...=\prod _{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1-t^{3\cdot 2^k}}{1-t^{2^k}}$$

$$B(t^2)=\prod _{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1-t^{3\cdot 2^{k+1}}}{1-t^{2^{k+1}}}$$
I'm stuck in this place and I don't know what to do next ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B(t)=(1+t+t^2)(1+t^2+t^4)(1+t^4+t^8) \cdots$, then

$B(t^2) =(1+(t^2)+(t^2)^2)(1+(t^2)^2+(t^2)^4)(1+(t^2)^4+(t^2)^8) \cdots$

$B(t^2)(1+t+t^2) = (1+t+t^2)(1+t^2+t^4)(1+t^4+t^8)(1+t^8+t^{16}) \cdots = B(t)$

QED

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$B(t^2)\frac{1-t^3}{1-t}=\prod_{k\ge0}\frac{1-t^{3\cdot 2^{k+1}}}{1-t^{2^{k+1}}}\cdot\frac{1-t^3}{1-t}=\prod_{j\ge1}\frac{1-t^{3\cdot 2^j}}{1-t^{2^j}}\cdot\left.\frac{1-t^3}{1-t}\right|_{j=0}=\prod_{j\ge0}\frac{1-t^{3\cdot 2^j}}{1-t^{2^j}}=B(t).$$

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $x^n$ in $B(x^2)(1+x+x^2)$ is $b_k$ if $n=2k+1$ is odd and $b_k+b_{k-1}$ if $n=2k$ is even. We want to show that this equals $b_n$.

If $n=2k+1$ is odd, then there must be exactly one summand $2^0$ in a representation of $n$ as sum of powers of $2$ when each power occurs at most twice. After removing this summand and halving all remaining summands, we obtain a valid representation of $k$, and vice versa, by doubling each summand of a representation of $k$ and adding $2^0$, we obtain a valid representation of $n$. Therefore, $b_n=b_k$ in this case.

If $n=2k$ is even, there must be either no summand $2^0$ or two such  summands. In the first case, halving takes us to a representation of $k$, in the second case, removing the $2^0$'s and halving takes us to a representation of $k-1$. Again, this map between representations is invertible, hence $b_n=b_k+b_{k-1}$ in this case.